# How can I count in R how many times an occurence appears?

Tags: analysis

If I have a data frame in R:

```
item, city 
1, Turin
2, Rome
3, Napoli
4, Turin
5, Rome
```

I want to count how many times each city appears and put this number of times in another column that I call counter. How can I do that in R ?

Comment: What is the column structure like? Does the cell with the city also have the number in it?

Comment: No it has only the city like this :

Comment: item,city
1,Turin
2,Turin
3,Rome
I want to count how many times a city appears : 
That means : Turin,2 and Rome, 1

Comment: Have you tried a Pareto Table?

Comment: No. Is there a package I should install for that ?

Comment: Did the answer that I gave work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is called city.df and the name of the column is city:

```
data.frame(table(city.df$city))
```